# Bean property 'feedId' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Below is code Batch snippet:
XML :
    
        </beans:property> -->

```
<beans:bean id="RDFieldSetMapper" class="in.gov.tds.batch.mapper.RDFieldSetMapper"
    autowire="byName" scope="step">
    <!-- <beans:property name="feedId" value="429717"></beans:property> -->
    <beans:property name="feedId" value="#{jobParameters[feedId]}"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

setter method in Java Class:

recordDetail.setFeedId(new Long(feedId));

Please provide the resolution as I am getting Invalid setter method.

More Mapper detail:
public class RDFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper {

```
private Long feedId;
private int batchCounter;

@Override
public RecordDetail mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug("Record Detail Mapper:-- " + " " + fieldSet);

    RecordDetail recordDetail = new RecordDetail();

    // feedId = FeedReader.feedId;
    recordDetail.setFeedId(new Long(feedId));
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the problem. Issue : setter and getter methods are not present in the mapper class.

```
public Long getFeedId() {
    return feedId;
}

public void setFeedId(Long feedId) {
    this.feedId = feedId;
}
```